# wxpython horizontal listctrl

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxglade

I want to display a list of icons in horizontal format in wxpython. I'm using `wxglade` and I can't find how to set list's orientation. Each item has an icon and below that it has a caption. Is this kind of design possible?

Comment: Ive never seen anyone who wanted to do this.... I dont think you need a list control though...

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
class MyList(wx.ScrollPanel):
   def __init__(self,the_list,parent):
      wx.ScrollPanel.__init__(self,parent,-1)
      self.SetMinSize((parent.GetSize()[0],-1))
      sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
      for Item in the_list:
           sz.Add(Item)
      self.SetSizer(sz)
      self.Layout()
```

where each item in the_list is a wx.Panel that includes your icon and text...

something like this at least... its untested... and no idea how you would do it within wxGlade

Answer (score 0):

The ListCtrl doesn't support that in report mode. I suppose you might be able to do it with one of the other style flags though. However Joran has the right idea. However, I would create a series of wx.Image or wx.StaticBitmap widgets and add them to a horizontal BoxSizer instead of what he did.